# Remove or Disable "Add a Network Location"

Tags: windows, group-policy

I've not been able to find anyway to do this via registry or GPO. I want to remove standard users ability to right-click computer and open the "Add a Network Location" button, or just disable the wizard from coming up. Is there any possible way to do this? I can't seem to find anyone successful with this.

Comment: I did a quick search for an answer and came up empty, as I'm sure you did too. There's a good reason for this: removing "Add a Network Location" will do nothing to prevent a user from typing in a UNC path. You might be better off securing your file shares instead of worrying about the "Add a Network Location" button.

Comment: I don't know how to block access to certain DLL calls, but the command that runs is `rundll32.exe shwebsvc.dll, AddNetPlaceRunDll`  If you can prevent that command specifically from running then you should be getting somewhere.  No idea what kind of impact that would have though overall.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a user from adding and disconnecting a network drive via group policy.

1. User Configuration
2. Policies
3. Administrative Templates
4. Windows Conponents
5. Windows Explorer
6. Remove "Map Network Drive" and "Disconnected Network Drive"

[image]

This removes the buttons and ability to map and disconnect network drives.  The right click function is still available but they cannot map to a local drive (it's only available to map to FTP sites and external websites).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great solution but you could always just remove access to the default context menu in Group Policy under the File Explorer section. I have searched for days on how to remove the "Add a Network Location" from the File Explorer ribbon UI and have not found a way to do this yet on a per user basis but here's how you can remove it system wide, just backup the following registry keys somewhere first and then delete them.

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.AddNetworkLocation`

`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.AddNetworkLocation`

It does make the explorer bar look a little strange with the entry missing so if you wanted to just disable the command from running, you can just delete out the data on the "(default)" entry under the "command" key for each location.

***UPDATED*** After more toying with it, I found that if you add the following registry values you can effectively "disable" the command.

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.AddNetworkLocation\AttributeMask`

Set value to REG_DWORD "00100000" hexadecimal

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.AddNetworkLocation\AttributeValue`

Set value to REG_DWORD "00100000" hexadecimal

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.AddNetworkLocation\ImpliedSelectionModel`

Set value to REG_DWORD "00000000" hexadecimal

Comment: This only disables the ribbon icon, but it doesn't remove the option in context menu. Any idea how to remove that as well?